# Accordion using AngularJS and CSS animations

Tags: css, angularjs, accordion, css-animations, expandable

Using just Angular JS Animate and Css Animation, I am trying to create an Expand/Collapse (Accordion) similar to the bootstrap collapse seen here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

I have an issue with the expandable items, they pop back and forth depending on height of the expanded "show" content. See my Plunker for more a visual

My work so far:

```
var expandCollapseApp = angular.module('expandCollapseApp', ['ngAnimate']);

expandCollapseApp.controller('expandCollapseCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.active = true;
    $scope.active1 = true;    
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/wBYsFM?p=info

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use [UI Bootstrap Accordion](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion). This component is written in pure AngularJS.

Answer (score 1):

```
  <div class="list card benefit-listCard">
    <h3 class="accordion" ng-class="{active:accordion1}">
<a href ng-click="accordion1=!accordion1" style="padding:0px;"><div class="item item-avatar benefit-itemAvatar">
    <img src="img/aws.png" class="service-img">
    <h2>Amazon Web Services</h2>
    <button class="button button-small button-outline button-calm detail-button">Get Deals</button> <div 
  class="fa fa-fw list-arrow" ng-class="{'ion-minus-circled': accordion1, 'ion-plus-circled' : !accordion1}" style="float:right;color:#44c8f5;font-size:25px;margin-top:10px;">
  </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Lorem Ipsum1

### Cytrus Pay

Get Deals
        
      
      
  
        
          Lorem Ipsum2.

### Amazon Web Services

Get Deals 
      
      
  
        
           Lorem Ipsum 3

Answer (score -5):

jQuery UI has a similar method you could use?

http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the team does not want to use jquery :(

Comment: @user2832814 You've referenced bootstrap, and you use AngularJS, if you are using both you should use http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: @user2832814 you should tell them jQuery is built into angular. It is.  It really is. http://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq. In fact it will forgo it's own jquery implementation (called jqlite), if query is present when angular is bootstrapped.

Comment: To say that jQuery is built into angular is like saying that your car has a built in jet engine when in reality you only have a desktop fan. Just because the desktop fan will be automatically replaced when you add the jet engine does not mean you had a jet engine all along. jqlite is a TINY utility that mimic a subset of some jQuery functions. (And in this example don't think of the jet engine as jQuery is fast, think of it as a jet engine is really heavy)